# How to average five images together with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-image

I have five UIImages and I want to average each individual pixel value: take the average color of the pixel value at each of the five images, so that in the end we have a new image made from the five images. How can you do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `CIFilter` and its amazing collection of filters.

Apple's predefined CoreImage filters for blending images are [here with illustrated results](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW71).

In my example I'm blending two images, then using the result to blend with a third one (and so on upon your needs).

I'm using the `CIAdditionCompositing` filter for my demo but other could be better for you, such as `CIColorBlendMode`, etc.

```
let img1 = CIImage(contentsOfURL: img1Source)
let img2 = CIImage(contentsOfURL: img2Source)
let img3 = CIImage(contentsOfURL: img3Source)

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")!
filter.setDefaults()

filter.setValue(img1, forKey: "inputImage")
filter.setValue(img2, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")

let resultImage1 = filter.outputImage

filter.setValue(img3, forKey: "inputImage")
filter.setValue(resultImage1, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")

let resultOfThreeBlendedImages = filter.outputImage
```

*Of course if you were to choose this solution, you'll probably want to refactor this into a function that takes an array of images and returns the blended result image.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var outputImage : CIImage?
var images: [CIImage] = []
images.append(CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0)))
images.append(CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0)))
images.append(CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0)))

let avg = 1.0 / CGFloat(images.count)
let divImage = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: avg, green: avg, blue: avg))

for image in images {
    if let divFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIMultiplyBlendMode", withInputParameters: ["inputImage":image, "inputBackgroundImage":divImage]) {
        if let avgImage = divFilter.outputImage {
            if outputImage == nil {
                outputImage = avgImage
            } else {
                if let addFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing", withInputParameters: ["inputImage":outputImage!, "inputBackgroundImage":avgImage]) {
                    let addImage = addFilter.outputImage
                    outputImage = addImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may use these sample images to compare results:

```
let sampleImage = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1.0/3.0, green: 1.0/3.0, blue: 1.0/3.0))
let t1 = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1.0/3.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0))
let t2 = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0/3.0, blue: 0.0))
let t3 = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0/3.0))
```